# Suggestions for embedded interactive analytical functionalities?

Tags: data-visualization, interactive-visualization, recommender-system

We're thinking of adding an interactive near real-time analytics functionality (a-la "Google Analytics") to a product Movie Recommender Engine.

We need to let the user interactively create analyses deciding on a case by case basis the analysis dimensions (e.g. by Genre, by Actor, by Publisher), metrics (e.g. Views, Purchases, Ratings) and the time window of the analysis.

We're considering several options like:

- charting libraries + custom built
- reporting engines (e.g. BIRT)
- OEM interactive analysis tools (e.g.
  Tableau)

Our solution is Oracle and java-based. The front-end is built using the Liferay Portal framework

Comment: I removed the link to your company as it is not necessary to understand the question and answer it.

Comment: @ chl. OK. Tx. Relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I love interactive visualization software like Spotfire and Tableau because it is easy to use and very insightful. My MBA students also become addicted.

I am more familiar with Spotfire, so I can say that they have a nice solution (Spotfire Silver) that allows you to create a dashboard of visualizations and post it to the Web so that users can play with a structured visualization or answer particular queries of interest.

Comment: Tx for the fast answer. The key point is that I need to have this as an EMBEDDED functonality in an existing SW solution. So with Spotfire (very nice) and Tableau (even better) the only option is an OEM agreement that (if available) is  prohibitively expensive...

Comment: yes, Spotfire Silver is very cool, very attractive visually, and it's available on a one-year trial. I fell in love just looking at the demos; it's easy to believe that anyone could become addicted. But it seems only to know about Oracle and MSSQL databases. It looks like it won't run on, say, the usual Linux server which often has MySQL only: Oracle would be uncommon and MSSQL impossible. Have you any insights as to how Spotfire is going to address those issues?

Comment: Dear @Pete - the Spotfire Analytics Server integrates into your existing information and analytics technology infrastructure, including databases like Oracle, IBM DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft Access, MySQL, SAS/SHARE, Sybase, Informix or any custom JDBC data source